# Winter Bash Leaderboard's search is not working with umlauts

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020, winter-bash

When trying to find myself at the [Winter Bash Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) I noticed that the search can't deal with umlauts.

When I search for `Bill T` I can find myself, but if I type `Bill Tü` I no longer get any matches.